# Create controls dynamically on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, dynamic-controls

I am trying to create dynamic controls on button click.

**HTML:**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSrt" runat="server" Text="Multi Sort" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="10pt" />
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="mpeSrt"
 TargetControlID="lnkSrt" PopupControlID="pnlSrt" CancelControlID="btnClose">
 </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:Panel ID="pnlSort" runat="server" align="center" Style="display: none" BackColor="LightGray">
              <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Sort By Column" />
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColumnSort" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
              <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Order By" />
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrder" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
              <asp:ListItem Text="Ascending" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Text="Descending" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
              </asp:DropDownList>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Sorting" Font-Underline="true" OnClick="lnkAddOrder_Click" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="Black" />
              <asp:Button ID="btnSorting" runat="server" Text="Sort" OnClick="btnSorting_Click" />
              <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
            </asp:Panel>
         </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**CODE:**

When clicked on AddSorting I am trying to create dropdown control using below code and the controls doesn't show.

```
protected void lnkAddSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = pnlSort.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>().ToList().Count + 1;
    this.Createddl("ddldyn" + index);
}

public void Createddl(string id)
{
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.ID = id;
    pnlSort.Controls.Add(ddl);
    Literal lt = new Literal();
    lt.Text = "<br />";
    pnlSort.Controls.Add(lt);
}
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pnlSrt` is set to `display: none` so the dynamically added child controls will not show either.

Comment: It works now. The controls is visible when I click on the first time, if I click on the button for 2nd time the second dropdown is not getting added. Updated post with image for better clarity. Also the dropdown is not getting aligned correct to the first row.

Answer (score 0):

As per the @Yoshi answer. You could set visible `true` for the `pnlSrt` control by using `pnlSort.Style["display"] = "block";// or pnlSort.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");`

Try this

```
public void Createddl(string id)
{
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.ID = id;

    pnlSort.Controls.Add(ddl);

    Literal lt = new Literal();
    lt.Text = "<br />";
    pnlSort.Controls.Add(lt);
    pnlSort.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
}
```

Comment: It works now. The controls is visible when I click on the first time, if I click on the button for 2nd time the second dropdown is not getting added. Updated post with image for better clarity.  Also the dropdown is not getting aligned correct to the first row.